# A simple understanding of negative percentage

Tags: absolute-value, percentages

I am currently working on a financial reporting setup and wondering about some percentages. If you have a result of a column with a margin of -16%, and the next period is -64%, is it correct to use -285% decrease? I have looked around searching for a valid explanation, but seem to get some vague answers. The theory that something cant decrease more than 100% doesn't seem usable when i have a situation with negative results. Is there any other way i can phrase it than to use the negative 285%? I used the absolute formula in excel.

Comment: May I ask, what was the calculation that you used to get $-285~\%$ ?

Comment: i used the percentage formula (b-a)/|a|, and used the absolute formula in excel (abs formula).